# Prove that a circle can be inscribed in the quadrilateral $ABCD$.

Tags: geometry

Prove that a circle can be inscribed in the quadrilateral $ABCD$.

[image]

---

The problem is reduced to prove that $AC + BD = AB + CD$

My attempt:

$1)$ $\triangle OBD \sim \triangle OBD$, by SAS congruency (two parallel sides and common angle $\angle O$)

$2)$ $AC \parallel BD,$ by $1)$

$3)$ $OB = OD$, by the Tangent-Tangent Theorem.

$4)$ $OA = OC$, by the Tangent-Tangent Theorem.

$5)$ $OB - OA = OD - OC \\
\hspace{27.5pt}AB = CD$

$6)$ $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid, by $2)$ and $5)$.

Therefore, the problem is reduced to prove that $AC + BD = 2AB$ or $AB = \frac{AC+BD}{2}$, the median of the trapezoid.

---

Here I'm somewhat stuck. I think I know how to prove this (it's just a successive application of the Tangent-Tangent Theorem showing that $AK = KM$, $CP = CM$, etc.), but what I don't know is what allows me to assume that the median of the trapezoid is tangent simultaneously to both circles. Could it be the secant of one of the two circles?

Just by looking the drawing, it seems to be tangent, but I would like to write it in the proof in a way in which the picture is not needed. For instance, in the way $1)$ is stated $2)$ follows right from it, even if there were no drawing.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $AK=KM=BK$ and similarly $AP=DP$, so $KP$ is a line connecting midpoints of sides of trapezoid, thus $KP=\frac{AC+BD}{2}$, so you only need to show $AB=KP$. But one easily sees $M$ is a midpoint of $KP$, so $KP=2KM=2KA=AB$.

Comment: I think I'm getting that, but before carrying out the proof of the equalities of those segments, how can I prove that $PK$ is simultaneously tangent to both circles?

Comment: What is the definition of line $PK$? I have taken it to be the common tangent to the two circles.

Comment: If there is any doubt about the segment $KP$ drawn in the figure, draw the figure over, constructing your own segment that is tangent to the circles where they are tangent to each other and that terminates on the edges $AB$ and $CD.$ Then proceed with the proof as shown in this answer, but use your constructed segment instead of $KP.$